# how I could replace in gsub ruby using a replace string with regex command?

Tags: ruby, linux, gsub

I have a command:

```
ruby -e ' variablea="MTH;VERDER;GHK" ;variableb="MTH;VERDER;GHK"; input=variableb.gsub("#{variablea}".gsub(/.+?;(.*?);.+/,"\\1.+"),"2"); print input ' >fffc
```

I need to replace `MTH;VERDER;GHK` using a regex command `VERDER.+` generated by substitution `"MTH;VERDER;GHK".gsub(/.+?;(.*?);.+/,"\\1.+")`  for obtain `MTH;2`.

I understand that the question may be strange but what happens is that I have simplified my approach so as not to make it too complicated to understand.

In summary I'm trying to use a *regex command* for replace originated from *a string will replaced*.

My problem is that replace string is treated as string, I cannot use as a regex command.

Comment: Please show the string you wish to obtain; e.g., `"MTH;2;VERDER;GHK"` or `"MTH;2"`?

Comment: i need "MTH;2" but i need to use a regex string generate from replaced string 
because I have a problem with a multiple array that i omitted of the question because this could be more complicated this question

Comment: Why not `variablea.partition(";")[0]+";2"`? It is **very** unclear what you are trying to do. Good sign why it is hard to do it. The first `gsub` you have `variableb.gsub("#{variablea}",...` simply produces an empty string.